# How can I view the contents of an array within controller directly for debugging?

Tags: python, pylons

I'm just getting started with pylons, and am trying to figure out how to view the contents of variables for debugging without rendering the template.

For example:

```
class IndexController(BaseController):

def index(self):
    # Return a rendered template
    #return render('/index.mako')
    # or, return a response
    return render('/index.mako' )

def test(self):
    v = request.params
    return v
```

I would like to view the contents of array v, but I can't figure out how to do it !!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cgitb](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html) to debug web applications, it can output detailed tracebacks to files, including variables contents. Here is [an article](http://blog.doughellmann.com/2010/01/pymotw-cgitb-detailed-traceback-reports.html) detailing how to use it.

If you can see the server stdout you can also simply `print` the variable, or else write it to a file: `open("my-debug-log.txt", "w").write(repr(variable))`. [pprint](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) can help making complex data structures (nested arrays, complex dicts, etc...) easier to read in this case.

Comment: Thanks!  However I'm just looking for something really simple to display the contents of a variable without rendering it in mako.

Comment: You can simply write the repr of the variable you want to see in a file then, or print it if you see the server's console.